# Intellij IDEA doesn't build maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to build project using "Hammer button" in Intellij IDEA, but it looks like compilator can't find JEE packages:

[image: idea errors]

But, when I'm trying to build project using Maven (clean, install) everything is OK, where can be problem?

I've got installed **adoptopenjdk1.8** and I'm using mac

**PS:** Invalidating cache and restart didn't work

Comment: Please provide bigger/full log. Seems like it's not picking dependencies..

Comment: You need to tell IntelliJ to use your JDK.  Default is to use the one bundled.

Comment: I'm using 1.8 SDK version in Project Settings, you mean that setting?

Comment: As said in the first comment this seems as it does not pick up dependencies properly. @yaw have you validated it?